# How to stop a jquery function inside iframe

Tags: jquery, html

I've a js file included inside the html file which is being called in iframe. I'm looking for an jquery function to replace the execution of js called inside the iframe by jquery function declared outside the iframe.

Like for example we have menus in the iframe and it slides to the section having parallex effect. I simply want the jquery function linked to slide should not work which is declared inside a js file inside an iframe.

Lets say following html code is inside of an iframe:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nitsmenu" data-nitspagelabel="1">
        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#navigation">Home</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#ourteam">Our Team</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now it has a `main.js` file which has the following code:

```
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 79
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Now I want this to be in editing mode where user clicks on the ul section a button appears which edits the order of menu or delete or add it. so I tried following steps in parent `editor.js` file:

```
$('#nitseditpreview').load(function () { //The function below executes once the iframe has finished loading
    var menu = $(this).contents().find('#nitsmenu');
    all_li = $(this).contents().find('ul#nitsmenu > li');
    $(all_li).find("a").removeAttr("href");
    $(all_li).find("a").css({
        'color': '#000'
        , 'background-color': 'none'
    });
    menu.hover(function (event) {
        $(this).css('border', 'solid 2px #8080ff');
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
    });
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        stop(); // where this prevents default or stops the event called in main page of js
       //....executes the function....
    });
 });
```

I want to stop using function used in `main.js`. But when it is outside the iframe I need the main.js file again.

Comment: Are the inner and the outer frame on the same domain?

Comment: Yes I'm following the rules.

Comment: In that case you can access the outer frame's functions from the inner using `window.parent.myFunction` (or even `window.parent.$(...)` but I'm not sure if this is a good idea), or the other way round using `myIframe.contentWindow.myFunction` (or if you have the IFrame as jQuery object, `$myIframe.get(0).contentWindow.myFunction`). So instead of replacing something, you can have the inner frame call a function in the outer frame. However it still sounds a bit weird to me and I wonder if there is a better architecture - could you explain your use case a bit further?

Comment: I'm making a web editor where end user can change menu design or the menu text, so far I'm calling my iframe with an id and executing the following: `$('#editpreview').load(function () {
  var menu = $(this).contents().find('#menu');
  all_li = $(this).contents().find('ul#menu > li');
  $(all_li).find("a").removeAttr("href");});` after the document is being ready

Comment: OK but I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve by replacing code and stuff. If you don't want something to happen in the IFrame, then just don't put code there which makes it happen!

Comment: ohk I got your point, so is there any other way round, like if the document is loaded from iframe we can escape a jquery function. As if irame is removed I need the jquery function back.

Comment: Now I completely lost you. It now sounds like you want jQuery *in the outer window* to change its behavior while an IFrame exists? This is making less and less sense. Can you add the info from your previous comment to the question please, and add more context and examples, especially what code exactly is the one you want to change behaviors, where and how you call it, etc.? It would probably be best if you would upload your whole code - unless you can't make it public.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please review.

Comment: I think the problem is much clearer now, thank you! I would think you could either avoid the iframe altogether and have the editing features in the same frame as the menu itself (which would make sense if you want to react on things like clicking on menu items anyway), or just load the frame content with a special query parameter or something to remove the animation code from main.js (or set a debug variable from the outside using `$('#nitseditpreview').get(0).contentWindow.myDebugMode = true;` or so)...

Comment: That's true, well thanks for the advice, but in the parent element I've the same fixed menu bar of 50px height which conflicts and displays overlapped...:(

Comment: OK then you would need to use my second solution...

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You are a savior...)

Comment: Great to see that it helped you. I turned it into a real answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state in the comments that you can't have the editor and the preview in the same frame, I'd suggest that you tell the inner frame that it is being edited and what to do or not to be, for example by setting a certain flag from the outside.

This can be achieved using code like the following (in the outer frame):

```
$('#nitseditpreview').get(0).contentWindow.myDebugMode = true;
```

Then, the inner frame just needs to check `if(window.myDebugMode)` to see if the flag is set in order to disable the animations, for instance.